# Creating State List Drawable XML for Background - Android

Tags: java, android, xml, layout, colors

I am trying to get the following state list to work. The idea is to create a white background.

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<item android:state_window_focused="false" android:state_selected="true"         
android:drawable="@android:color/transparent" /> 
<item android:state_selected="true" android:drawable="@android:color/transparent" /> 
<item android:state_pressed="true" android:state_selected="false"    
android:drawable="@android:color/transparent" /> 
<item android:state_selected="false" android:drawable="@color/WHITE" /> 
</selector>
```

When I try and compile this I get the following error..

`@color/transparent and @color.WHITE don't exist.`

Do I need to define these somewhere and if so how ?

Thanks !

Comment: `@color/transparent` exists as `@android:color/transparent`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try to create a resource file like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
<color name="white">#ffffff</color>
</resources>
```

let's see if someone knows about transparent one

Answer (score 1):

I think the only problem is you are referencing directly a color instead of an actual `Drawable`. Try creating a `ColorDrawable` first and use it in your `StateListDrawable`.

When creating a `ColorStateList` (which is different from `StateListDrawable` because it's a list of colors and not `Drawable`s) you can directly use colors ...

Answer (score 1):

You must use `@android:color`, otherwise it doesn't know where the color is defined.

```
android:background="@android:color/white"
```

Answer (score 1):

In Android's Color Palette there is no defined transparent 
[Android Color Palette](https://material.google.com/style/color.html#), however you could define opacity and that will generate the sense of transparency, here is a good sample about how to use it: [Hex transparency in colors](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15852122/hex-transparency-in-colors)

Here's a code snipet about how to declare a custom color in res/value/colors.xml

`<color name="colorWhite">#FFFFFF</color>`

now with transparency:

`<color name="colorWhite">#FFFFFFFF</color>`

being used in the state list:

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<item android:drawable="@color/colorWhite" android:state_hovered="true"/>
</selector>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<color name="white">#aarrggbb</color> will set the transparency
<color name="white">#80ffffff</color> will set white color with transparency value 80.
```