# Create a new color drawable

Tags: java, android, android-drawable, colordrawable

I am trying to convert a hex value to an int so I can create a new color drawable. I'm not sure if this is possible, but according to the [documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/drawable/ColorDrawable), it should. It plainly asks for

> **public ColorDrawable (int color)**
>
> Added in API level 1 Creates a new ColorDrawable with the specified
>   color.
>
> **Parameters** *color*    The color to draw.

So, my code isn't working because I'm getting an Invalid int: "FF6666" error. Any ideas?

```
int decode = Integer.decode("FF6666");
ColorDrawable colorDrawable = new ColorDrawable(decode);
```

Comment: if one of the answers provided solved your answer, think of validating it as an accepted answer so the other knows your problem is solved.

Comment: There is a nice utility class android.graphics.Color that have a method parseColor. Try using it instead and don't forget to append the sharp (#) prefix to your colors string representation, e.g. #FF6666

Answer (score 193, accepted):

Since you're talking about hex you have to start with `0x` and don't forget the opacity.

So basically: **0xFFFF6666**

```
ColorDrawable cd = new ColorDrawable(0xFFFF6666);
```

You can also create a new colors.xml file into /res and define the colors like:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <color name="mycolor">#FF6666</color>
</resources>
```

and simply get the color defined in R.color.mycolor

```
getResources().getColor(R.color.mycolor)
```

Comment: what i needed is   `new ColorDrawable(getResources().getColor(R.color.red)))` thanks

Comment: ContextCompat.getColor(getContext(),R.color.red) for compatiability

Comment: can we change background color by using this **cd** which is colorDrawable type variable

Comment: On a side note, you can use ColorDrawable's for objects that require a Drawable such as DividerItemDecoration.setDrawable(); instead of using an actual drawable layout you can pass a ColorDrawable to simply change the divider's color.

Answer (score 31):

For using with ContextCompat and rehuse the color you can do something like this:

```
ColorDrawable colorDrawable = new ColorDrawable(ContextCompat.getColor(this, R.color.white));
```

Comment: What's meant by `this`?

Comment: @Christian Context

Answer (score 10):

It should be like this...

```
ColorDrawable cd = new ColorDrawable(0xffff6666);
```

Note I used 8 hex digits, not 6 hex digit . which [add to transparency](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17239853/2345913)

Comment: But you'd like to have such values in appropriate 'res' files, not hardcoded. Enrichman answer is complete :)

Comment: How is `cd` used in relation to `Toast`?

Answer (score 9):

By followingthe above advice,to be a summary of this question:

1. ColorDrawable colorDrawable = new ColorDrawable(**Color.parseColor**("#ce9b2c"));`
2. ColorDrawable colorDrawable = new ColorDrawable(**0xFFCE9B2C**); 
   **Note there is  8 hex digits, not 6 hex digit,which no work. Case all**
3. ColorDrawable colorDrawable = new ColorDrawable(ContextCompat.getColor(mContext,R.color.default_color));

Selecting up to you!

Comment: If I have an array of color then ?

Comment: @DPrince ，You can try this,
`int color = Color.HSVToColor(new float[]{...})
`
and then use above .

Answer (score 4):

I think you have to use :

> **public static int parseColor (String colorString)**
>
> Added in API level 1 Parse the color string, and return the
>   corresponding color-int. If the string cannot be parsed, throws an
>   IllegalArgumentException exception. Supported formats are: #RRGGBB #AARRGGBB red, blue, green, black, white, gray, cyan, magenta, yellow, lightgray, darkgray, grey, lightgrey, darkgrey, aqua, fuschia, lime,
>   maroon, navy, olive, purple, silver, teal

Answer (score 1):

> This is how I converted a Hex color to int and applied to a Background
>   of a View

Let's say that we have a color #8080000.

#### 1) Hex to int conversion

```
int myColor = Color.parseColor("#808000");
```

#### 2) Set background

```
view.setBackgroundColor(context.getColor(myColor));
```

Comment: `(context.getColor(myColor)` are you serious?! `(context.getColor(COLOR_RESOURCE_ID)`, it resource color id

Comment: What do you mean? @user924

Answer (score 0):

Xamarin/Maui :

```
  protected override void OnCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        base.OnCreate(savedInstanceState);      

        Window.SetBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(ColorExtensions.ToAndroid(Colors.Black)));
    }
```