# ContextCompat.getColor() returning -1 for any defined color

Tags: java, android, sdk

I am unable to retrieve the correct color value from resources.

From this [very good answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31590714/getcolorint-id-deprecated-on-android-6-0-marshmallow-api-23) from araks, we see that the old `getResources().getColor()` method has been deprecated for the new Marshmallow API's, thus

**My implementation**: (although very extended to find cause)

```
int resColorID;
if (//something here) {
    //some code
    resColorID = R.color.color1;
    //some code
    resColorID = R.color.color2;
    //some code
    resColorID = R.color.color3;
}
int resC = ContextCompat.getColor(context, resColorID);
ColorDrawable cDraw = new ColorDrawable(resC);
```

`resC` always, but always returns -1. For the life of me I cannot find anything on this,

the specified colors (they are arbitary names) `R.color.color1`, etc are all defined in `colors.xml`

**Extra Info:**

- minimum build sdk = 19
- compile + target sdk = 23

why does this happen?

Comment: maybe context has not initialised correctly. When do you call the code above? which activity lifecycle callback?

Comment: I have the same problem in my custom view.

Comment: @Sermilion I cannot remember how I resolved the problem, but have a look at this -> https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19407672/create-a-new-color-drawable