# Change Listview cell opacity

Tags: android, android-listview

I want to change the opacity of some cell of my `ListView`.

I don't know the color to apply, only the alpha, so I can't use :

```
v.setBackgroundColor(0x44FFFFFF);
```

I have to use somethings like :

```
v.setAlpha(50);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes you can use `setAlpha`.

The function `View.setAlpha(float)` expects a value between 0 and 1.

See here: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#setAlpha%28float%29

Answer (score 0):

You can try this too:

```
myView.setBackgroundColor(getResources()
            .getColor(R.color.translucent));//here translucent = "#80FFFF" ARGB format
```

Please refer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15852122/hex-transparency-in-colors) for more details on transparency values.