# Is it possible to convert rgba color to hex using LESS

Tags: css, less

I have an element(`<div>`) with transparent background color: `rgba(96, 96, 96, .1)` and I assume my element has a wrapper with white background.

Is there any way to convert transparent color to hex using LESS css? For example, `rgba(96, 96, 96, .1)` should be equal to `#efefef`.

I've read the [color function](http://lesscss.org/functions/#functions-overview) article, but have not found a suitable answer.

Comment: why do you want to do that? #curious

Comment: I think thats because hex is fastest. :)

Comment: how could you transpose the transparency information with hex format?

Comment: Any colour you get in hex will not be transparent

Comment: @FabrizioCalderan http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15852122/hex-transparency-in-colors There is somewhat limited support for that.

Comment: @TylerH that looks to be for android - transparency in hex isn't usually possible for CSS.

Comment: @AlexanderLozada Indeed, hence the "limited" :-)

Comment: 'why do you want to do that?' - in my application I have a palette that contains colors definition. For example, `@base_color: #606060; @hovered_state_color: fade(@base_color, 10%);` In some cases I can't use transparent colors and I want to use the similar colors but in hex or rgb format.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand the question correctly you're looking for a function that calculates result of compositing/layering of one color (e.g. `rgba(96, 96, 96, .1)`) with/over another (e.g. `white`). In Less it's supposed to be one of the [blending functions family](http://lesscss.org/functions/#color-blending), but since the name of such function in current naming convention has to be `normal` (which is rather weird) this function is not included. But if one of colors is always `white` you still can get the desired result via `multiply`:

```
multiply(white, rgba(96, 96, 96, .1))
```

Comment: You're completely right! It works fine, thanks a lot!