# Android - How to set color value to TRANSPARENT

Tags: android

how to get parseColor color value to transparent.

```
mPaint.setColor(Color.parseColor("#FFFF00"));
```

thanks for help

Comment: Check out this answer:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15852122/hex-transparency-in-colors

Answer (score 32, accepted):

Suppose your preferred color is red `#FF0000`

Adding 00 in the beginning will make it 100% transparent and adding FF will make it 100% solid.

**So, 100% transparent color is:** `#00ff0000`
**and 100% solid color is:** `#ffff0000`

And any value in between `00` to `ff` can be used to adjust the transparency.

Answer (score 7):

just used android color string

```
mPaint.setColor(getResources().getColor(android.R.color.transparent));
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use Color.TRANSPARENT if you do not want to change the transparency level.

```
import android.graphics.Color;

// use Color.TRANSPARENT
mPaint.setColor(Color.TRANSPARENT);
```

https://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Color#TRANSPARENT

Answer (score 0):

You can use Color.argb(int alpha, int red, int green, int blue)

Alpha corresponds to transparency. 0 for fully transparent. 255 for opaque.

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Color.html#argb(int,%20int,%20int,%20int)

> Return a color-int from alpha, red, green, blue components. These
>   component values should be [0..255], but there is no range check
>   performed, so if they are out of range, the returned color is
>   undefined.