# Is there a transparent color code?

Tags: android, transparency, background-color, android-drawable, color-codes

I'm looking for my actionBar to be transparent. I only have searchView in it and it's in my MapActivity, I just want the searchView and the "back pressed" buttons to be visible. Which transparency # code do I use to fill into the following:

```
 getSupportActionBar().setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(parseColor("#")));
```

Comment: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/drawable/ColorDrawable.html#attr_android:color May be a color value, in the form of "#rgb", "#argb", "#rrggbb", or "#aarrggbb".

Comment: Maybe https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30169507/android-how-to-set-color-value-to-transparent

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Android - How to set color value to TRANSPARENT](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30169507/android-how-to-set-color-value-to-transparent)

Comment: Transparency is usually the first channel on a color spec (ARGB) so you may declare it as #FF000000 (Full Transparent black color)

Comment: @MarcosVasconcelos maybe a typo but #FF000000 is not transparent. It's opaque black.

Comment: So its #00000000 ?? I always forget thats why I always use #88000000

Comment: Yes for #00000000. And NB: setBackgroundDrawable(Drawable background)  This method was deprecated in API level 16. use setBackground(Drawable) instead https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#setBackgroundDrawable(android.graphics.drawable.Drawable) NB2: background Drawable: The Drawable to use as the background, or null to remove the background

Comment: I wonder why I'm receiving down votes? The question is very clear.  I'm just asking the color code for transparency. It's not too complicated of a question, don't overthink it.

Comment: You can also use the short form: #ARGB. So, **#0000**.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Android supports the #AARRGGBB color format.

A = alpha, R = Red, G = Green, B = Blue

To make some View transparent use #00000000.
First 00 are alpha.

Comment: You can also use the short form: #ARGB. So, **#0000**.

Answer (score 1):

You can also try this **#ffffff00**

Comment: this is a fully transparent white actually