# Android transparent color in custom view class

Tags: android

I'm drawing a rect in the `onDraw()` of a custom view class. I want the color of the rect to be transparent (eg 50%) so that the background shines through.

Here's my layout.xml:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:background="@drawable/background"  >

    <MyCustomView
        android:id="@+id/myCustomView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

</LinearLayout>
```

The background is set in the `LinearLayout` as you see.

colors.xml:

```
<color name="my_tranparent_color">#77FFFFFF</color>
```

somewhere in `MyCustomView`'s `onDraw()` method:

```
Paint p = new Paint();
p.setColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.my_tranparent_color));
canvas.drawRect(new Rect(x, y, x + 20, y + 20), p);
```

The result isn't transparent, it's only kind of gray.

I get simular results if I set the alpha value inside the `onDraw()` method:

```
p.setAlpha(51);
```

and

```
<color name="my_tranparent_color">#FFF</color>
```

Comment: Are you sure? `#8fff` is semi-transparent white. `#8000` is semi-transparent black.

Comment: <color name="my_tranparent_color">#77FFFFFF</color> - This must work....try changing the alpha value in it from 77 to much lower one (for eg 22) in order to test

Comment: You can refer below link for get transparency.

http://stackoverflow.com/a/17239853/3374189

Comment: @DroidWormNarendra already tried that. It's like the alpha cahnel is used for grayscaling in my case...

Comment: You are **wrong**. For **sure**.

Comment: For 50% transparency, in your xml, try adding this attribute to your MyCustomView:

    `android:alpha="0.5"`

Comment: @Prince this actually works. But it sets the alpha channel for my whole view. I only want some elements of it to be transparent.

Comment: In that case, you can apply it directly to only those children views inside the `MyCustomView` that you want to be semi-transparent. You can also set it in code for your views like `yourToBeSemiTransparentView.setAlpha(floatValue);`

Comment: @Prince inside the class? I've tried that earlier as you see in my question `p.setAlpha(51);`

Comment: Apply it only to your _children Views_ that you mentioned are a few elements inside the _MyCustomView_ class rather than applying to _MyCustomView_ class as a whole. Also, #80FFFFFF will give you 50% transparency on White color.

Comment: @Prince those elements are rects that I draw inside the `MyCustomView` class. Can you give me an concrete example for that?

Comment: I see, in that case try setting a paintStyle: Some sample code- Paint p = new Paint();
        p.setColor(Color.parseColor("#FFFFFF"));
        p.setAlpha(50);
        p.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);
RectF draw = new RectF();
        draw.set(100, 100, 100, 100);
        canvas.drawRect(draw, p);

Answer (score 0):

Stupid me! The problem was that I was drawing black rect behind the white one. I didn't remember that it was filled with black, because I used it to get a border for the white rect. So the background for the white rect was a black rect, which explains the gray result. Thanks for your help :/