# Set background of ListView item based on percentage

Tags: android, listview, android-listview, parse-platform, android-parsequeryadapter

I have a list of [testNames, testScores] that I want displayed in a listView.

I want the backgrounds of the listView items to be covered by their respective testScore % in green.

For example, If I have 3 tests with scores 40, 70 and 100, then
I want the 3 listview items to have background 40% green, 70% green and 100% green.

I am using ParseQueryAdapter for setting listView's text as shown below.

```
//Retrieve number of tests for current user from Parse
ParseQueryAdapter.QueryFactory<ParseObject> factory =
         new ParseQueryAdapter.QueryFactory<ParseObject>() {

             public ParseQuery create() {
                  ParseQuery query = new ParseQuery("Tests");
                  query.whereEqualTo("username", currentUser.getUsername());
                  query.orderByAscending("testName");
                  return query;
             }
         };

final ParseQueryAdapter<ParseObject> adapter = new ParseQueryAdapter<ParseObject>(
                Home.this, factory);

//Display session string for ListView Selection
adapter.setTextKey("testName");

chooseTestListView.setAdapter(adapter);
```

The above code helps display the testNames in my listview. But I would like to know how to set the backgrounds of each of the list item's proportionally to the testScore.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you checked [Hex transparency in colors](http://stackoverflow.com/a/27813407/1276636)?

Comment: @Sufian - hey! Thanks! That does help. Now I can set the progressBar's color to translucent and I can view the text as well.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Hex transparency in colors](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15852122/hex-transparency-in-colors)

Answer (score 0):

Well for this you will need to create a custom adapter that extends parse query adapter of an object
There you can add a progress bar that is customized to look like a background and let the percentage equal to result

Comment: There's no need for to add a `ProgressBar`.

Comment: If not a `ProgressBar,` then use what?