# How to create semi-transparent activity/menu in android

Tags: android, transparent

How to achieve a menu similar to this one in the image? How can I display such a menu with semi-transparent background where I can see camera preview. What is the name of that kind of menu?

[image]

Comment: create a translucent image which will have 50% opacity and set it their background...

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15852122/hex-transparency-in-colors

Comment: @user3731565 you ccan check the answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/34281868/1140237

Answer (score 1):

Set semi transparent or fully transparent color to your layout(menu layout) background.
Below I have mentioned color code with transparency level

```
Black - "#000000"  

100% Transparent"#00000000"

100% Opaque "#FF000000"
```

`50% Transparent "#80000000"`  (This one you can use in your case)

For more details regarding Android color code you can check 
https://stackoverflow.com/a/17239853/1140237

Answer (score 0):

use this code

```
 <style name="MyTheme" parent="android:Theme">
         <item name="android:panelFullBackground">{your color or drawable}</item>
    </style>
```