# Sublime Text - Transparent Theme

Tags: themes, sublimetext3, alpha

Can alpha be applied to hex color code in Sublime?

Sublime themes can be edited through .tmTheme files by changing the hex values.

```
<key>background</key>
<string>#000000</string>
```

**Android:**`#32000000 black 20% alpha`
[Hex transparency in colors](https://stackoverflow.com/q/15852122/5893999)
does anything like this work?

**Purpose:** see desktop while coding

I only want to edit it through .tmTheme file for simplicity. Any help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, just add the an hexadecimal value at the end, for example for a black color with 50% opacity use `<string>#00000080</string>` or for a white color with a 50% opacity use `<string>#FFFFFF80</string>`

Source: https://www.sublimetext.com/docs/3/color_schemes.html

Comment: Doesn't provide desktop transparency, which is what OP wanted. Sublime Text doesn't support it.

Comment: @FreeBullets Desktop transparency can be achieved with any utility to do so, e.g. for windows you may use http://windowtop.info/

Comment: can you please help me with finding the f.themfile