# Android map EditText opaque

Tags: android, google-maps, android-edittext, transparent

I'm creating a custom drawable so that an EditText on top of a map has rounded corners. I'm trying to obey the correct parameters in the docs for [shape](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/drawable-resource.html#Shape). Specifically I am trying to set a white background using the solid field:

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <corners android:radius="5dp" />
    <solid android:color="#FFFFFF"/>
</selector>
```

and

```
<EditText
...
android:background="@drawable/text_box"
.../>
```

But the EditText is still transparent - I don't want the map to be visible behing the EditText.
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should create your resource first the drawable shape corner and background params:

myshape.xml:

```
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:shape="rectangle">
    <corners android:radius="5dp"/>
    <solid android:color="#BFFFFFFF"/>
</shape>
```

myselector.xml

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <corners android:radius="5dp" />
    <solid android:drawable="@drawable/myshape"/>
</selector>
```

And use the selector inside your edittext:

```
<EditText
...
android:background="@drawable/myselector"
.../>
```

BF... is for 75% opacity. H[ere you can found all opacity](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15852122/hex-transparency-in-colors)

Comment: Is it possible to do this with one additional file instead of two? Can you please explain why this works and my solution does not work?

Comment: You can use only myshape.xml if you want: **android:background="@drawable/myspahe"** .Generally you use selector if you need to specialize drawable for specific cases for example: a drawable for focus state another one for pressed state etc..