# I need to create Transparent control buttons for music player app in Android

Tags: android

I want to create control buttons for music player.My requirement is ,the buttons should be transparent. Means parent background should be visible through buttons. Please tell me how to do it.Which widget I should use?
Below is the image of my requirement.

Image is as below
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Pgdy2.jpg)

Comment: A `Button`, with `android:background="@android:color/transparent"`(I cannot see an image by the way)

Comment: take simple button and set it's background color as Color.TRANSPERENT

Comment: You forgot to attach the image of your requirement.

Comment: try to create shapes using xml shape drawable with @android:color/transparent as color.

Answer (score 0):

Set the property "alpha" of button between 0 and 1, where 0 is invisible and 1 visible:

```
<Button
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="New Button"
                android:id="@+id/button"
                android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal|bottom"
                android:alpha="0.5" />
```

Comment: This will also mean any text on the button has an alpha effect applied, not just the background.

Comment: Yes, he just said that background should be visible, not specified so much more

Comment: Hello Sir, I have uploaded the image

Comment: One way to do that is  using imagebutton with a source image in png with transparent background, and if needed set imagebutton background color to transparent too

Answer (score 0):

```
    please check below link and use to set like below
    http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15852122/hex-transparency-in-colors

    <Button
          android:layout_width="wrap_content"
          android:layout_height="wrap_content"
          android:text="New Button"
          android:id="@+id/button"
          android:background="#E6FFFFFF"  
        android:alpha="0.5" /> 


// here E6 is alpha code
// and i set it for white color(FFFFFF)
```

Comment: I'm new to stack overflow...not able to upload image