# How to make texts complete on a new line and make a layout with transparent color

Tags: java, android

I just create simple grid view like this [image: GridView]
all I need as you see the texts with long name I want it to complete the text in a new line not going to the other relative layout as I need also the relative layout with id/rlTXTnme with a green color but with transparent green color for example thats the image view in the parent relative layout should be showed like this grid item Example [image: Example GridView]
and this is my XML File

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:background="#ffffff"
        android:layout_height="125dp"
        android:layout_width="125dp"
        tools:layout_conversion_absoluteX="5dp"
        tools:layout_conversion_absoluteY="5dp"
        tools:layout_conversion_absoluteWidth="170dp"
        tools:layout_conversion_absoluteHeight="170dp"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="0dp"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="0dp">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageView"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            app:srcCompat="@drawable/ssttll"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="65dp"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:background="#dcffbc"
            android:id="@+id/rlTXTnme"
            android:layout_toStartOf="@+id/relativeLayout">

        </RelativeLayout>

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="35dp"
            android:layout_height="75dp"
            android:background="#f9762f"
            android:id="@+id/relativeLayout"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
            android:layout_below="@+id/button">

        </RelativeLayout>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView8"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textSize="25dp"
            android:text="0"
            android:textColor="#ffffff"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
            android:layout_below="@+id/button"
            android:layout_alignStart="@+id/relativeLayout" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button"
            android:layout_width="50dp"
            android:background="#ff2f2f"
            android:layout_height="75dp"
            android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:text="-"
            android:layout_alignStart="@+id/relativeLayout"
            android:layout_above="@+id/rlTXTnme" />



    </RelativeLayout>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/menuTVGrid"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:text="TextView"
        android:textColor="#000000"
        android:textSize="10dp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="0dp"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.601" />

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

Sorry for my bad Englishand sorry if any thing is unclear

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a linearLayout and set weights to the layouts.

And for the transparency of the background, android accepts colors in AARRGGBB format where AA is the percent value of transparency needed. A good doc for percent-to-hex conversion can be found on [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15852122/hex-transparency-in-colors) SO post.

Posting the edited layout in sometime

For transparency: if for 20% transparency:

`android:background="#33dcffbc"`

Comment: Could I do this in relative layout?? @MadScientist
thnks alot for your help am w8in for your edit post at this case :D

Comment: OK TYT Thanks alot @MadScientist for your help

Comment: there's nothing posted yet :) @MadScientist

Comment: oh, i was working but then you marked it as an answer so i asked!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/138019/discussion-between-madscientist-and-dev-7arooney).