# Reset Child opacity in react native

Tags: reactjs, react-native

So I have drawer which has background black with opacity 0.5 , it works fine.I can see transparency.Now problem is even the button is having opacity which I dont want , how to reset its opacity to 1 ?I tried RGBA , still opacity is not resetting in react native.

```
  <View style={{backgroundColor:'black',opacity:0.5,height:'100%'}}>

            <Button backgroundColor:'black',opacity:1>
              <Text>Click here </Text>
            </Button>

     </View>
```

Comment: Try using an [8 digit hex code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15852122/hex-transparency-in-colors) for you background color and remove opacity and see if that works.

`<View style={{ backgroundColor: '#80000000`, height: '100%'}}>

Comment: @alexdriedger : works mate , thanks

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use an [8 digit hex code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15852122/hex-transparency-in-colors) for your background color and remove opacity.

```
<View style={{ backgroundColor: '#80000000, height: '100%'}}>
```

Answer (score 3):

`Try to use a lighter background color and skip setting opacity altogether. Like so,

```
  <View style={{backgroundColor:'#111',height:'100%'}}>

            <Button backgroundColor:'black'>
              <Text>Click here </Text>
            </Button>

     </View>
```

***Edited answer*** 
I noticed that you are using Button. Better use TouchableOpacity or other touchables which are customizable using styles.
You can try setting the background color using the rgba property like so,

```
backgroundColor:'rgba(0,0,0,0.6)'
```

In your context, it would look like

```
  <View style={{backgroundColor:'rgba(0,0,0,0.4)',height:'100%'}}>
            <Button backgroundColor:'rgba(0,0,0,1)'>
              <Text>Click here </Text>
            </Button>
  </View>
```

[Snack](https://snack.expo.io/S1vx2Qp3g)

Comment: @Vishnu , I edited the answer. It does what you need.