# I want to add a transparent overlay to my background image in android

Tags: android, android-layout

I want to add a transparent overlay to my background image in Android, like below

[image]

My code

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="com.bykar.bykar_provider.WaitingForActivationActivity">

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:contentDescription=""
        android:scaleType="centerCrop"
        android:src="@drawable/map_bg"
        tools:ignore="ContentDescription" />

    <View
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="@color/black"
        />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Did i write something wrong?I test your code and it worked in my android studio.So I posted that answer?can I know the reason for my answer not right?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just add opacity to the background color. On this example if you wish to add 70% opacity to your black color then change the background color to the hex code `#B3000000`

If you want a list of HEX transparency codes just check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15852122/hex-transparency-in-colors) answer

Answer (score 13):

Add the background to view as 20% opaque

```
<View
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#26000000"/>
```

Here are the opacity values if you need:

```
100% — FF
95% — F2
90% — E6
85% — D9
80% — CC
75% — BF
70% — B3
65% — A6
60% — 99
55% — 8C
50% — 80
45% — 73
40% — 66
35% — 59
30% — 4D
25% — 40
20% — 33
15% — 26
10% — 1A
5% — 0D
0% — 00
```

Comment: The values you provided here worked for me to make the transparence more darker. thank you

Comment: I am glad that helped you