# Custom dialog with white transparent background

Tags: android, android-layout, android-activity, dialog, android-alertdialog

Required output image:

[image]

I have tried the code and my output is like this. Kindly help me to produce the output as I have shown.

**My code:**

In Activity:

```
@OnClick(R.id.imageView)
    void imageTapped() {
        Dialog alertDialog = new Dialog(this);
        alertDialog.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
        alertDialog.setContentView(R.layout.photo_dialog);
        alertDialog.getWindow().setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(Color.TRANSPARENT));
        alertDialog.show();
    }
```

In XML (R.layout.photo_dialog):

```
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/tabLayout"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:gravity="bottom"
    android:background="@android:color/transparent">


    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btn1"
        android:layout_width="@dimen/_200sdp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="#3ca49c"
        android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_margin_half"
        android:paddingLeft="@dimen/_40sdp"
        android:paddingRight="@dimen/_40sdp"
        android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_margin_half"
        android:text="Take Photo"
        android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/_20sdp"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:textColor="@color/white"/>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btn2"
        android:layout_width="@dimen/_200sdp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="#3ca49c"
        android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_margin_half"
        android:paddingLeft="@dimen/_40sdp"
        android:paddingRight="@dimen/_40sdp"
        android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_margin_half"
        android:text="Choose Existing"
        android:layout_below="@id/btn1"
        android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/_20sdp"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:textColor="@color/white"/>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btn3"
        android:layout_width="@dimen/_200sdp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@color/white"
        android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_margin_half"
        android:paddingLeft="@dimen/_40sdp"
        android:paddingRight="@dimen/_40sdp"
        android:layout_below="@id/btn2"
        android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/_40sdp"
        android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_margin_half"
        android:text="Cancel"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:textColor="#3ca49c"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

My output:

[image]

I need a white transparent background and the alignments as shown in the required output image. Kindly help me with some suggestions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Try this :**

Use color code for white transperent : #B3ffffff

```
Dialog alertDialog = new Dialog(this);
        alertDialog.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
        alertDialog.setContentView(R.layout.photo_dialog);
        alertDialog.getWindow().setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(mContext.getResources().getColor(R.color.white_transperent)));
        alertDialog.show();
```

You can adjust this hash code according your transparency requirement.  [use link](http://stackoverflow.com/a/17239853/8089770)

Comment: upvote an answer if it solved your problem