# How to add a mask over background image in activity?

Tags: java, android

I want to add an image as a background of an activity, and I want to add another image .png over it

Comment: Read https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: `How to add a mask over background image in activity?` add a layout with transparent background !!
 https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15852122/hex-transparency-in-colors try this

Comment: @MatarUano Please [BE NICE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/be-nice) to community users, everyone here is volunteering to help you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just add two `imageview` on top of each other using a `relative layout`

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <ImageView
        android:scaleType="centerCrop"
        android:src="@drawable/settings"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />
    <ImageView
        android:alpha="0.5"
        android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />

</RelativeLayout>
```