# Parent Relative Layout Foreground Color affecting Textview Color

Tags: android

I need relative layout background with some transparent for that i used gradient option, But it is affecting text view color also , I gave color of text view is white color but it looks like gray color. Please help me to get out of this issue.

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/topLayout1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="210dp"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:foreground="@drawable/image_overlay"
    >

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/topLayout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="@drawable/preloader_image"
        >
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/resName"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_marginTop="100dp"
            android:text="Green Way"
            android:textColor="@color/White"
            android:textSize="25sp"
            android:backgroundTint="@color/White"

            />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/desc"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@+id/resName"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
            android:text="@string/items"
            android:textColor="@color/White"
            android:textSize="16sp"
             />

    </RelativeLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

and image overlay code,

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <gradient
    android:startColor="#B0000000"
    android:centerColor="#A0000000"
    android:endColor="#00FFFFFF"
    android:angle="270"
    />
  </shape>

<color name="White">#FFFFFF</color>
```

Comment: Can you show the hex code of `@color/White`?

Comment: @BachVu , I gave #FFFFFF only.

Comment: if you want transparency try using android:alpha"0.9"

Comment: Your problem is this line `android:foreground="@drawable/image_overlay"`, any reason why you choose `foreground` instead of `background` here?

Comment: What kind of layout do you want? Can you provide a screenshot of the desired layout?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `#83000000` color code for setting transparency and that too in `android:background` instead of `android:background` property. Alternatively, you can also use `"android:aplha="0.x"` where 1 < x < 9, for transparency. Your final code will look like this.

```
<RelativeLayout android:id="@+id/topLayout1"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="210dp"
android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
android:background="#83000000"
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/topLayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/resName"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="100dp"
        android:text="Green Way"
        android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
        android:textSize="25sp"
        android:backgroundTint="#FFFFFF" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/desc"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/resName"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
        android:text="Items"
        android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
        android:textSize="16sp" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

You should see this [ANSWER](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17239853/7976274) to know more about transparency. You can use various hex codes to achieve different level of transparency. Like for 50% transparency `80` code is used and color code would be like `#80000000`. Similary, you can use various codes in the scheme `#xx000000`.