# How to put transparent color for container in flutter

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

I want to put opacity for container which contain hexadecimal color code.

This is my color:

```
const color_transparent_black = const Color(0x80000000); //50%
```

As you can see i add `80` mean 50 % transparency.

```
return Scaffold(
  backgroundColor: Colors.amber,...
  Container(
    // card view
    alignment: Alignment.center,
    margin: EdgeInsets.only(
        top: 20.0, bottom: 10.0, left: 30.0, right: 30.0),
    decoration: BoxDecoration(
      boxShadow: ([
        BoxShadow(color: Colors.black, blurRadius: 5.0)
      ]),
      color: main_color_transparense_black,
      borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(14.0),
    ),
    child: Column( ...
```

But `Container` is not transparent and it is completely black?I know with `Opacity` widget it is possible but i want to do this with color?

I read this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55294676/how-to-put-opacity-for-container-in-flutter)

This is not my answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The code has no issue with you `Color(0x80000000)`

You are seeing black color is due to the box shadow color back. `BoxShadow(color: Colors.black, blurRadius: 5.0)`. Try to change your BoxShadow as per your needs. Try giving some offset value for the shadow.

Comment: I change BoxShadow to this: `BoxShadow(color: Colors.black54, blurRadius: 5.0)` and the problem gone. Thanks