# Adding blur effect to transparency overlay

Tags: java, android

Can't find solution for adding blur effect to transparency overlay to place over a video background in a native Android app.

Have tried alpha etc but these solutions do not work over video, only images.

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?><LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="match_parent" android:background="#ffffff"> <LinearLayout android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="match_parent" android:weightSum="105" android:orientation="vertical"> top layout with image <LinearLayout android:background="@drawable/s" android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="match_parent" android:layout_weight="45"> </LinearLayout> <FrameLayout android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="match_parent" android:layout_weight="60" android:weightSum="75" > <ImageView android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="match_parent" android:alpha="0.5" android:adjustViewBounds="true" android:scaleType="fitXY" android:src="@drawable/s"/> <LinearLayout
```

At the moment I can only place a transparent overlay over the background video, I am unable to add a blur effect. Any suggestions?

Comment: Add a background to the layout itself.. You can try adding alpha to a color by referring this https://stackoverflow.com/a/17239853/6514945

Comment: hope Blurry library may solve your porblem 
https://github.com/wasabeef/Blurry

Comment: Responding to both suggestions above;

1) This makes view transparent, not blur. Also transparency does not work with VideoView.

2) These are for Imageview and bitmaps, this will not work for VideoView.

Comment: Any other suggestions?

Comment: I heard there is a $1m prize for any poster that doesn't have their question answered?