# Set ConstraintLayout background color to transparent

Tags: android, android-constraintlayout, android-background

I want to set background color to transparent. I've tried with this [SameProblem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15852122/hex-transparency-in-colors) but it doesn't work.

This is the my interface. I need the first ConstraintLayout to be transparent I used "android:background="#00000000" " but no result (background white).

[image]

This is my xml file :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout 
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="#00000000"
tools:context=".AddEditNote">

<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
    android:id="@+id/constraintLayout2"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="6dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="26dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="6dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="26dp"
    android:background="@drawable/a"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/note"
        android:layout_width="343dp"
        android:layout_height="487dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="44dp"
        android:background="@color/cardview_shadow_start_color"
        android:hint="Note"
        android:inputType="textMultiLine"
        android:textColorHint="@color/aidialog_background"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.509"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent" />

    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="393dp"
        android:layout_height="49dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="4dp"
        android:background="@drawable/circle2"
        android:elevation="4dp"
        android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:theme="?attr/actionBarTheme"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.6"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

  </android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
  </android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

Thank you.

Comment: background="@null" to get rid of a background though just getting rid of the background="#000" should work since usually the layouts don't have a background by default

Comment: Wait, what's behind your constraing layout? are you sure there is something? if not then why do you want it to be transparent?  If there is nothing behind its natural that you'd see white

Comment: I want just to show the second constraints layout (that’s why I need to set first one background color to transparent)

Answer (score 0):

You can try deleting the `android:background="#00000000"` attribute, or changing it to `background="@android:color/transparent"`.

Comment: still don't wrok

Comment: background="@android:color/transparent or ="null" not working

Answer (score 0):

We can use LinearLayout as parent of the ConstraintLayout

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#fff">

    <android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="#000"
        tools:context=".MainActivity">

     ...

    </android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: This is not a good option to add a wrapper for ConstraintLayout when you can simple add the  android:background="null" instead

Answer (score 0):

Add the attribute to your XML: **android:background="@android:color/transparent"** or **android:background="null"**

This will remove your background color and make it transparent.

If you want to read move about ConstraintLayout - https://developer.android.com/training/constraint-layout

Comment: still don't wrok

Comment: you cannot add "null", because there is no "null" attribute in the android:background

Comment: @Cyd Yes, you can

null means no background at all (View.getBackground() returns null).
#00000000 means that you got a ColorDrawable as the background which has a fully-transparent color.
If you don't want to have a background make it null it should perform better. To use null from the code you can try doing:

Comment: @EdgarKhimich :( it's not working for me. i've been doing all the suggestions here for 3 hours now and still not working for BottomSheetDialogFragment.

Answer (score 0):

You need to change the alpha in the color code to increase or decrease the amount of Transparency :

1.You can range it from 00 to FF (Hex Decimal)

2.For maximum transparency => #ff______ (Here ff stands for the alpha)

3.For minimum or no transparency => #00______ (Here 00 stands for the alpha)

so simply add
`android: background="#00000000"`
to your constraint layout