# Add opacity to hex representation of color

Tags: javascript, colors, hex, transparency, background-color

I have a color code, for example `#EB5757` which is a kind of red. I want to add opacity to it `0.15` or 15%. After looking on [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15852122/hex-transparency-in-colors) I saw in the accepted answer that for 15% one must add `26` at the beginning.

So I did it: `#26EB5757` but now the resulted color is not a red with opacity but a green. I'm using this in Javascript/React if this information is useful.

```
style = {backgroundColor: '#26EB5757'}
```

Any ideas on how to set that original red color to be opaque?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

8 digit hexadecimal color notation in CSS has the following format:

```
#RRGGBBAA

RR - red
GG - green
BB - blue
AA - alpha
```

You should use:

```
#EB575726 (for your 15% red)
```

Answer (score 0):

I guess you can use convertor to get actual RGB representation of that HEX.
You may try this [one](https://www.rgbtohex.net/hextorgb/)

Then you can simple add your opacity into `rgba` like this  use `backgroundColor: rgba(235,87,87, 0.15)`