# Transparent header in specific screen on React navigation 5

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, react-navigation

I am upgrading my code from React Navigation 4 to 5. For a stackNavigator I had the following configuration before.

```js
const whiteNavOptions = {
  headerStyle: {
    backgroundColor: "white"
  }
}

const transNavOptions = {
  headerTransparent: true,
  headerTintColor: "white",
}

const VenuesNavigator = createStackNavigator(
  {
    Venuefy: VenuefyScreen,
    VenueDetail: {
      screen: VenueDetailScreen,
      navigationOptions: transNavOptions,
    },
    Sorting: SortingScreen,
  }, {
  defaultNavigationOptions: whiteNavOptions
}
);
```

So now I am trying to map it like this in React Navigation 5

```js
const VenuesStackNavigator = createStackNavigator();
const VenuesNavigator = () => {
  return <VenuesStackNavigator.Navigator screenOptions={whiteNavOptions}>
    <VenuesStackNavigator.Screen name="Venuefy" component={VenuefyScreen} options={VenuesScreenOptions} />
    <VenuesStackNavigator.Screen name="VenueDetail" component={VenueDetailScreen} options={VenueDetailScreenOptions}/>
    <VenuesStackNavigator.Screen name="Sorting" component={SortingScreen} />
  </VenuesStackNavigator.Navigator>
}
```

I have set default `screenOptions` to `whiteNavOptions`. Now I want to set the `transNavOptions` to the `VenueDetailScreen` only. Maybe something like this:

```
<VenuesStackNavigator.Screen name="VenueDetail" component={VenueDetailScreen} options={VenueDetailScreenOptions} screenOptions={transNavOptions}/>
```

It's is not clear from the documentation, how can I do that? I know I must be missing something obvious but any pointer to that obvious would be much appreciated x)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

documentation has [this example](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/headers#adjusting-header-styles)

```
function StackScreen() {
  return (
    <Stack.Navigator>
      <Stack.Screen
        name="Home"
        component={HomeScreen}
        options={{
          title: 'My home',
          headerStyle: {
            backgroundColor: '#f4511e',
          },
          headerTintColor: '#fff',
          headerTitleStyle: {
            fontWeight: 'bold',
          },
        }}
      />
    </Stack.Navigator>
  );
}
```

which means headerStyle is basically accepting styleProps so in backgroundColor pass in some opacity like described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15852122/hex-transparency-in-colors)

or i think you should be able to do something like this

```
declare style obj
const transparentStyles = {
    backgroundColor: 'white',
    opacity: 0.5,
}
```

and pass it to screen options like

```
...
function StackScreen() {
  return (
    <Stack.Navigator>
      <Stack.Screen
        name="Home"
        component={HomeScreen}
        options={{
          title: 'My home',
          headerStyle: transparentStyles,
          headerTintColor: '#fff',
          headerTitleStyle: {
            fontWeight: 'bold',
          },
        }}
      />
    </Stack.Navigator>
  );
}
```

But if i were you i would be simply creating custom header JSX component so i have full controll of everything