# Getting error while changing the opacity of color by 20 % transparent in android color resource file

Tags: java, android

I am trying to change the opacity of color to 20% transparent but when I add this hex code '33' in this color hex code '#FF2F2F2F' my code editor gives me error.

The color in res/values/**colors.xml** file

```
<color name="windowDark">#33FF2F2F2F</ color>
```

Comment: correct it as `<color name="windowDark">#33FF2F2F</color>`

Comment: I have changed but still gives me an error.

Comment: what is the error its giving you?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Easy set opacity with percentage check this**

```
red color color code is = "#eb4336"
now set opacity before color code like this

#10eb4336 (first 10 is opacity 10%) you use easy like 

10% = #10eb4336
20% = #20eb4336
30% = #30eb4336
```

Answer (score 3):

you can not make a Opaque which is already a Opaque . Its `ARGB` that's 8 bit for each .

[image]

If your color hex is `#2F2F2F` then you add Alpha in front of it i.e `#332F2F2F` .if you want to change the alpha then just change the Starting two.

`FF` in your example color code is value of Alpha. You do not need `FF` in your color anyway that's goes for 100% Alpha. Anyway when u wanna change the alpha you just replace `FF` with `33`. See [This thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15852122/hex-transparency-in-colors) for opacity .